# Native crash on an Android-Java based app?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, dalvik, crash-reports

### Background

[**My app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) has 100% code written in Java, it doesn't need to make any heavy operations.

The app itself uses only the next libraries, yet non of them have JNI code:

- ActionBarSherlock
- google-play-services_lib

### The problem

Today I got a weird crash report, which doesn't show any normal exception information .

The report was sent via a "Galaxy S5 (klte)" device, with Android 4.4 .

Here's the crash report title:

```
Native crash at /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache in
/dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
```

And here is the crash content :

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/kltexx/klte:4.4.2/KOT49H/G900FXXU1ANE2:user/release-keys' 
Revision: '14' 
pid: 11904, tid: 11904, name: .lb.app_manager >>> com.lb.app_manager <<< 
signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR), fault addr 6d7b97cc SOME_NUMBERS

backtrace:
#00 pc 00026a56 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
#01 pc 00026a55 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)

code around pc: SOME_NUMBERS

code around lr: SOME_NUMBERS
```

where "SOME_NUMBERS" look like a lot of random hexadecimal numbers.

### What I've tried

Some websites claim people should decode images in a synchronized manner (yet I have made many apps that do it and never got this error).

The thing is, for this app I already decode the bitmaps using a single thread, so this can't be it.

I didn't find any other thing that can be related to things I do on the app, that have anything to do with native handling of code.

I thought, maybe since it's Android 4.4, the user moved to "ART" runtime, but the crash report has the word "dalvik" in it, so that's probably not it (and even if it was this, I have no idea how to handle it).

To make things even more unclear, the user wrote "Not sure" in the report... :(

### The question

How could this be?

Why does it occur?

How can I fix it?

Anyone else had this issue before?

Comment: Kinda sounds like something wrong with the platform and not your app.

Comment: @Mgamerz Since it looks like Galaxy S5, how could it be that a brand new device with a mature OS would have this issue?

Comment: How does Windows 8.1 crash?

Comment: @Mgamerz nice one :) , but Samsung has less devices to handle than Windows

Comment: That doesn't mean there aren't issues.

Comment: Have you figured out this mystery in the meantime?

Comment: @user1987392 Did you get this crash too? It's very rare, so I have no idea if it got fixed or not, and also what fixed it. Only thing I do is to keep the libraries (and SDK) I use to be most updated, hoping that this would fix everything...

Comment: Yes. On an alpha app (not in production yet). Uses google-play-services_lib but no ActionBarSherlock. Device was a Galaxy S4 (jflte) and the user's message in the error report was "App wont open". Other than that, it's similar to your scenario: `Native crash at /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache`, hex numbers, etc.

Comment: @user1987392 How odd. I've left ActionBarSherlock too. I hope it won't occur anymore.

Comment: I'm seeing this in my crash reports, the class is the IntentService I'm using to update a home screen widget. What is very weird is that my widget has two variants, one 3x2 and the other 4x3. Only the 3x2 has this error when trying to update the widget for the first time, the other not.

Comment: I have very similar problem: a plain Java Android app crahed with `signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000` in `/dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache` (device is `motorola/obake-maxx_verizon/obake-maxx:4.4.4`). Google Play reporting tools do not provide any Java context (stacktrace) to pinpoint it (any ideas?). I guess, if it would be an error in my Java code, the error occured often, but it's only 1 time, so it seems like Android bug.

Comment: Maybe try to update whatever you can . Other than that, I have no idea how to handle those things...

Comment: What can we update? In my case this happend (once so far) on a user's device and reported via Google Play.

Comment: @Stan Update Android-Studio. Update SDK. Update all modules. Update support library. Update everything... Also use latest SDK (targetSdk set to 22)

Comment: Possibly related: [Native crash at /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545557/native-crash-at-dev-ashmem-dalvik-jit-code-cache)